# Python equivalent of list() function in R

Tags: python

I have defined a list in R in following way:

```
list(type_ = "angles", units = "radians", 
     template = "none", modulo = "asis", zero = 0, 
     rotation = "counter")
```

I tried using the list() function of Python but it does not allow me to assign values to objects in the list. 
I also tried defining a dictionary but I can't define it the following way:

```
{type_ = 'angles', units = 'radians', template = 'none',
 modulo = 'asis', zero = 0, rotation = 'counter'}
```

Since it gives me syntax error and if I change the "=" sign as ':', it gives me an error saying "type_" variable not defined.

How do I define such a list in Python?

Comment: It is not a list in Python.  Try dictionary in Python.

Comment: And also, you have to set the keys for Python.  Such as {"type_" : "angles"}

Comment: The appropriate data structure in Python would be a `dict`. Using your `dict` literal, the keys need to be in quotes as well (since you want strings presumably) and the pairs are separated by a colon, so `{'type_' :'angles',  'units':'radians' ...}`. Alternatively, you can use the `dict` constructor just like you would use `list` in R, so `dict(type_='angles', units='radians' ...)`